# Execute addEventListener() inside a function

Tags: javascript, performance, dom-events

**What I wanted:** Add an event listener to window on scroll, *but only* when a certain function is fired. The way I wanted it to work is:

1. execute `foo()`
2. inside said function, `window.addEventListener("scroll", bar());`
3. then, *and only then,* have `bar()` be executed upon every single scroll (until I decide to `removeEventListener()` somewhere else).

**What happens:** `bar()` only gets executed once - during the life span of `foo()`, I suppose.

A **workaround** is to

1. add the event listener outside of the function (globally),
2. encapsulate the code in `bar()` inside `if (some_boolean === true) {`,
3. set my `some_boolean` variable (declared globally) to true before `foo()` ends.

That way, I got the scroll functionality I needed, **but now** `bar()` and its boolean check gets executed upon **every scroll**, when there's absolutely no need to.

**Question:** How do I add the event handler so that it runs bar() efficiently?

Comment: Use `window.addEventListener("scroll", bar);`...Remove `()`..It will invoke the handler initially not when `scroll` takes place..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`bar()` appears to be called, not referenced at `window.addEventListener("scroll", bar());` . Try referencing `bar` as handler to call when `scroll` event occurs

```
window.addEventListener("scroll", bar);
```

Comment: This solved my problem. I thought in addEventListener(*event*, *script*), the complete signature of the function in *script* is needed (I come from a Java background and am new to JavaScript). Thank you!

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "complete signature". In JS, there are function references, such as `bar`, and function invocations, such as `bar()`. What you need to pass to **any** interface that takes a function as a callback is the function reference.

Comment: @SamuelLOLHackson See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener

Comment: `bar()` would not be `invalid` syntax either but value returned by `bar()` should be `function expression(JavaScript function)`

Comment: @torazaburo Sorry, I used Java terminology here. A method signature (note: they're called methods rather than functions) for a method like, for example, `void bar() {/* ... */} `, would be `bar()`. I can't think of any way to simply write `bar` in Java and have it be syntactically correct, so my brain got hard wired to include these () brackets...But that's off topic.